# Display jquery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script here , i don't know how to pass this variable to display it.

```
   function show(a) {
    this.name = a;
    $("#box").show();
    $(document).on("click","#box",function() {   
    alert(this.name);
    } ); 
    }
```

i know i can just alert it like this

> alert(a);

but in my real code, i have a dynamic variable soi need to pass tit and display it using this method:

> alert(this.name);

Comment: because the context of `this` is not the same in those 2 places.... I think you can just use `function show(a) {
     $("#box").show().click(function () {
         alert(a);
     });
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bind`:

```
function show(a) {
    this.name = a;
    $("#box").show();
    $(document).on("click","#box",function() {   
        alert(this.name);
    }.bind(this) ); 
}
```

`bind` returns a function, which is bound to a specific context. This way you have the right context. When you change the property `name` the context object, your alert shows the correct `name`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Also a good article about `Function.prototype.bind`: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/

Answer (score 0):

Because `a` is defined in the closure, you can just use `a` everywhere, instead of trying to work with `this`.